# Delay mouse down event responsiveness

Tags: c#, touch

I am using resistive touch screen. On tapping button on resistive touch screen, I am changing background color of button to green, on upon mouse up event I am removing background color of button using c#, and it works fine in resistive touch.

But in case of capacitive touch, the responsiveness of capacitive screen is faster and when I tap on button i dont see change of button background color, because mouse down happens faster and so mouseup happens faster, and our eyes are nit able to see the change of color.

hoW to solve this issue by changing any settings in windows 10 to delay the latency of touch in capacitive touch?

Tried changing touch latency in registry but it didnt solve the issue.

Comment: Don't mess around with any global settings, use a Task.Delay in your mouse up event handler to delay the change of color a little while.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i have many buttons in my application like and i dont want to  change code in all the buttons

Comment: Then make a common function and call that in all event handlers, or create your own "DelayButton" with overriden handling off events. You cannot expect there to be configuration to solve every possible problem or design someone have.

Comment: Thanks JonaH, it works fine for resistive touch screen, but for capacitive touch screen is the problem. Will do changes for all the button, if no other solution